# Is there a way to programatically get the current Code Signing Identity and/or Provisioning Profile of an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm developing an iPad application, and my testers (which don't have a development environment) need to know if the app they are using has Production or Development certificates (this is because push notifications are sent to different servers depending on the certificate being used)

Is there a way to programatically get the current Code Signing Identity and/or Provisioning Profile of an app?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243855/how-to-detect-that-a-provisioning-profile-is-for-development-or-distribution-pr ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is no, but you could have defines setup for Debug/Release/Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit to the AppStore you can retrieve both your Code Signing Identity and the provisioning profile from the binaries you build.

The signing identity is visible with `codesign -d -vvv AppName.app/Name`, so you'll need to do some macho plumbing to get that, and the provisioning profile can be found in `AppName.app/embedded.mobileprovision`.

After submission, the provisioning profile is ripped out and the signing identity is changed to Apple's.

I'm not sure that this is a great way to solve your problem.