# iOS push notification device token for development and production

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does anybody know if device tokens for iOS push notifications are the same for development and production builds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Client get a different device token when registering themselves in development builds vs applications downloaded from the App Store.

Take note that the device token in the production environment and the device token in the development environment are not the same value.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

Comment: Thanks, I've completely overlooked this sentence!

Comment: Maybe this reference helps too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243855/how-to-detect-that-a-provisioning-profile-is-for-development-or-distribution-pr

Comment: the reference is a broken link

Answer (score 2):

The production APNS system is completely separate from the development (sandbox) APNS system.  There are separate certificates, and server addresses.  When you run the application using a development provisioning profile, the sandbox APNS is what will be used, when you either archive an application (using a distribution profile) or submit the application to the App Store, the production APNS is responsible.