# How to detect if app installed from AppStore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

My application can be installed from Appstore, and also via Enterprise distribution.
The code is completely same.
So how can I programmatically differ if Application was installed from Appstore?

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to know if someone logged-in as you and installed a particular app?

Comment: You could probably not find any information because what you want doesn't make any sense. @trojanfoe I'm glad I wasn't the only one that sounds like what they want

Comment: @Popeye Agreed; voting to close.

Comment: @trojanfoe same voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @trojanfoe, please check this question again. Edited.

Comment: @Popeye, please check this question again. Edited.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense. Are you just wanting to identify the company that made the app? If so why not just check the `bundleIdentifier`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get part of the way there by reading in the embedded.mobileprovision file from the application bundle:

```
NSString *provisionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded" ofType:@"mobileprovision"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:provisionPath]) {
    // Appstore version
}
```

If that does not exist, you are in an app store build.

If it does exist, you need to figure out some difference between your debug and ad-hoc provisioning profiles, and look for that to determine which build you are in.

Regarding to /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
This is a safe way, you can check `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`,
that's the path from where images and resources are loaded,
it starts with /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/...

So reading/checking your bundle files, will not cause rejection.

Comment: Hmm thanks it looks useful. It returned something like that. provisionPath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FCxxxxxxxSomeNumbers/MyOwnApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision.  If it is app store build then provisionPath will return nil? or it will still return until  /MyOwnApp.app/ ?

Comment: May I make a small point, notice the word `private` in the path. You shouldn't really be accessing things in the private folder at all and this will probably get your app rejected

Comment: @Popeye, your Application bundle is there, so you can't access your bundle?

Comment: @yucelbayram you need to check using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:provisionPath];`

Comment: @Popeye Yes thanks for the help. I did not notice that.

Comment: @yucelbayram `I0gg3r` is right it is your own bundle so it shouldn't really make to much of a difference but if a folder is called private I always edge on the side of caution, because we all know what Apple is like, but on an App store released app it wouldn't return anything anyway.

Comment: @Popeye Yes This app already on appstore. I m trying to make new version. But you are right about private. I am trying to change this private stuff.

Comment: @yucelbayram you will not get rejected 100% ,

Comment: Answer partially plagiarises https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089150 Would have been nice to give credit where due.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not identify that. If you have shared the credentials to anyone else and if he has downloaded the app using it, there is no way for you to check the same.