# How can i know if an app is installed from apple app store or other stores in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there any method to know if an app is installed from App store of OSX or installed from some other places?
I want to implement this using object c.

Comment: @ThomasW This is about an OS X app, not iOS.

Comment: OK, even if it is not for OS X, I suspect the answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087779/detect-appstore-installation-of-ios-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the app came from Apple's app store by attempting to validate the receipt. You can read about receipt validation in the [*Receipt Validation Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH105-SW1), and searching for something like "mac app store receipt validation" will turn up a number of [samples like this one](https://gist.github.com/sazameki/3026845). Apps that are downloaded from sources other than Apple's app store won't have valid receipts.